# Simulate radio buttons using checkboxes and only trigger change event once?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, radio-button

I would like to simulate radio button behaviour using checkboxes, this says :

> When a checkbox is checked, all other checkboxes with the same name (here, selector) are unchecked

But, if I try to do something like :

```
$('body').delegate('.myradio', 'click', function(e) {
    $('.myradio').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

This trigger the `change` event twice.

If I try to add a `e.preventDefault` :

```
$('body').delegate('.myradio', 'click', function(e) {
    $('.myradio').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

No event are triggered at all and the checkbox isn't checked.

Finally, if I try to trigger the event myself :

```
$('body').delegate('.myradio', 'click', function(e) {
    $('.myradio').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).change();
});
```

The `change` event is also called twice.

For information, all my checkbox have unique IDs.

What is the propper way to disable all checkboxes except the one checked ?

Comment: This may be an obvious question here, but if you want a checkbox to behave like a radio button, why not just use a radio button?

Comment: Because that behaviour depends on what is checked elsewhere : in some contexts, user may be able to check several checkboxes.

Comment: you could use a timeout and ignore an event that is fired e.g. twice in 100ms, but that would be really dirty ;)

Comment: Not a bad idea. A timeout with 0 milisecs made the job. :-)

Comment: @Ninsuo so should you be able to deselect a checkbox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, following should work.

```
$('body').delegate('.myradio', 'click', function (e) {
    var $element = $(this)[0];
    $('.myradio').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0] !== $element)
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

This way the checkbox group behaves like a radio button group. Except that you can de-select a selected item.

---

Below code makes the group behave more like a radio group. You can't de-select once you made a selection.

```
$('body').delegate('.myradio', 'click', function (e) {
    var $element = $(this)[0];

    if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
        return;
    }

    $('.myradio').each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0] !== $element)
            $(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this if you still want to be able to unselect a checkbox

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){ // <-- use the change event
  var group = $(this).attr('name'); // get the group
  $('input[name='+group+']').not(this).prop('checked',false);  // set others to unchecked
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rmJpB/

Answer (score 0):

You can use on() function.

```
$('body').on('click', '.myradio', function(){
  $('.myradio[name="'+$(this).attr('name')+'"]').prop('checked', false);
  $(this).prop('checked', true);
});
```

Uncheck all the other checkboxes with the same name, check the current checkbox.

http://jsbin.com/ofibow/2/edit